# Does "$n$ related strategies such that at most one fails" imply a single strategy that fails with probability $\le 1/n$?

Tags: probability-theory, puzzle

In a generalized "prisoners/hats/boxes"-style logic puzzle, suppose we have the following:

- a set $W$ (of "possible world configurations")
- a set $S$ (of "possible individual strategies")
- a relation $C\subseteq W\times S$ (representing "individual success criteria")
- a solution $(s_1,\dots,s_n)\in S^n$ with the property that $\forall w\in W, |\{j\in\{1,\dots,n\}:(w,s_j)\notin C\}|\le1$.

That is, the solution gives $n$ individual strategies that are "correlated" so that at most one will fail.

Intuitively, then, if I choose $j$ uniformly at random from $\{1,\dots,n\}$ and follow strategy $s_j$, then my probability of failure is at most $1/n$. Is this true?

Surprisingly, the answers on [this MathOverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151286/probabilities-in-a-riddle-involving-axiom-of-choice) (which is this exact question for a specific puzzle) argue that the answer is no. They seem to assume that in order to answer the question, we need a probability measure on $W\times S$; then $C$ is the event of interest and needs to be measurable, which is where problems arise.

But do we really need to bring $W$ into the probability space? We've made no assumptions of randomness about $W$. The probabilistic strategy is just a probability measure $\Bbb P$ on $S$ (assigning probability mass $\frac1n$ to each of $s_1,\dots,s_n$ and $0$ to all other strategies), and for each $w\in W$, the event $C_w=\{s\in S:(w,s)\in C\}$ is a $\Bbb P$-measurable subset of $S$. We have

$$\forall w\in W,\Bbb P(C_w)\ge\frac{n-1}n.$$

Does this not justify the informal conclusion that the probabilistic strategy guarantees success probability $\frac{n-1}n$?

Comment: The [top answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/151539/59232) shows why your logic fails with the continuum hypothesis example. Let $X,Y\sim \text{Unif}[0,1]$ independently, and let $\prec$ be a well-order of $[0,1]$. Assuming CH, for all $y\in [0,1]$, we have $P(X\prec y)=0$, so your logic would imply $P(X\prec Y)=0$. However, $P(X\prec Y)$ must be $1/2$ if anything. I agree your logic is tempting, but we cannot trust our intuition when the axiom of choice is in play.